# Accessing Asterisk Recorded Calls , built in solution

Tags: asterisk

dose asterisk have any solution to access the recorded calls by itself , i mean no tricky way like saving recorded calls to DB or using Ftp or other third party solutions ...
looking for built in solution.

Answer (score 0):

No.
But you can build a macro that will play the recorded calls

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk does not provide a built in mechanism to access recorded calls (via Monitor or MixMonitor). All calls will be recorded to /var/spool/asterisk/monitor (unless specified differently).

You can check out a project called ARI (Asterisk Recording Interface), not to be confused with Asterisk REST Interface. It should provide you with the solution you are seeking.

Pay attention to one thing - recording everything into a single directory will end up with thousands of files in one directory. Depending on your file system, ext3/4 for example, may not really like the idea that there are 10,000 files in one directory.

My suggestion to you is this, if you are building a recording system for an enterprise, develop a catalog mechanism with a database, so that you don't have to run daily archiving and sh**ty procedures to keep your system working.